# HTML to Text Conversion in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I have a bunch of org-mode files with snippets containing HTML code and I would like to convert those to plain text.

I don't need any fancy fully automated solution, I can just past my HTML snippet into a scratch buffer if that's easier.

Here's a simple example of desired behavior:

```
<div><div>First Line<br>Second Line</div></div>
```

```
First Line
Second Line
```

What are the options available to Emacs users for such a task?

Answer (score 2):

Emacs added EWW in Emacs 24.4 (2014), the Emacs Web Wowser, a built-in web browser . The shr.el library is used for rendering HTML, e.g.,

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert
   "<div><div>First Line<br>Second Line</div></div> ")
  (shr-render-region (point-min) (point-max))
  (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))

;; =>

"First Line
Second Line
"
```

`shr-render-region` uses `libxml-parse-html-region` which requires your Emacs has libxml2 support.

Answer (score 0):

[html2org package](https://github.com/lujun9972/html2org) seems to get the job done

`html2org` function converts and replaces the HTML code as text.